# Apriori and association rules with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apriori

Is it doable to create an Apriori app using map-reduce?  I am starting out but it's not clear how to create the next Candidate sets based on a previous run.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Yes Apriori algorithm is doable - generating frequent itemsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be useful to have a look to Apache Mahout. It is a machine learning and data mining framework in Java which abstracts sending MapReduce jobs for clustering, recommendation and classification tasks.

It seems the apriori algorithm is not implemented (there is one jira issue marked as won't fix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-108), but maybe other algorithm could be useful for you.

Even if you only need the apriori algorithm, it could be useful to have a look at their source code to get some ideas.

Comment: But I don't know how to use it。there are no any source code but  pitch....Have any other info？